# Creating keys and its value inside a dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I want to create a dictionary in which each key will have names like `doc1`, `doc2`,....,`doc2105` and it will store value from `Title_Loans.documents[0]`,`Title_Loans.documents[1]`,....,`Title_Loans.documents[2104]`.
I am trying to run a for loop on length(`Title_Loans.documents`) inside a dictionary but it is showing error:

```
for i in range(len((Finance.documents)):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Below is the code I am running. Please suggest me how this can be done.
Code:
Sample:

```
docs = {
    'doc1': Title_Loans.documents[0],
    'doc2': Title_Loans.documents[1],
    'doc3': Title_Loans.documents[2],
    'doc4': Title_Loans.documents[3],
    'doc5': Title_Loans.documents[4]
}
```

Trying to run above code using for loop for large document size.

```
docs = {
for i in range(len((Finance.documents)):
    doc[i]: Finance.documents[i]
    }
```

Comment: @Rakesh or has one too many ☺

Comment: I changed it but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: You are mixing two syntaxes : normal for loop and dict comprehension (the latter being `docs = {i : Finance.documents[i] for i in range(len(Finance.documents))}` which you could more simply put : `docs = dict(enumerate(Finance.documents))`

Comment: Not a proper dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a dictionary comprehension then you have to use comprehension syntax, not a statement (comprehensions are expressions):

```
docs = {"doc"+str(i): Finance.documents[i]
        for i in range(len(Finance.documents))}
```

This would, however, be much better written as

```
docs = {"doc"+str(i): documt for (i, documt) in enumerate(Finance.documents)}
```

I am unsure, though, why a dict that can be accessed with keys like "doc1", "doc2", etc. is better than a simple list, which can be accessed with integer keys.

Comment: This is not working. Showing error: }
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `doc[i]` is not what the user is expecting, her requirement is key name like `doc1`, `doc2`

Comment: To start with 'doc1' you would need `str(i+1)`

Comment: Actually I want to create a document-term matrix using different lists as separate documents and that's why I converted it to a dict.

Comment: Does this mean the terms are held in a separate list?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in range(len(Finance.documents)):
```

for your `invalid syntax` error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your keys to take the form "doc(num)" then create a string
`doc_format = "doc{}"`

then run:

`docs = {doc_format.format(index+1): Finance.documents[index] for index in range(len(Finance.documents))}`

Comment: Or enumerate over the list:


`docs = { doc_format.format(index+1): f for index, f in enumerate(Finance.documents)}`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct [dict-comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) syntax, it should be:

```
{key, value for key in your_iterable}
```

> where, value can be some function of `key` or vice-versa

For your case:

```
docs = {"doc{}".format(i + 1): Finance.documents[i] for i in range(len(Finance.documents))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as well,

```
doc = {}
for i in range(len(Finance.documents)):
   doc[i] = Finance.documents[i]
print(doc)
```

Comment: OP is getting syntax errot in `dict-comprehension`, your answer does not address that.

Comment: Are you iterating list right? or elaborate where error occurs?